# Springboot, mybatis doesn't map DateTime during Unit Testing with Junit

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, junit4, mybatis

I have the following **DateTimeTypeHandler** class:

```
//Copyright 2012 Lucas Libraro
//
//   Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
//   you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
//   You may obtain a copy of the License at
//
//       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
//   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
//   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
//   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
//   See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
//   limitations under the License.
package com.common.mybatis.typehandler;

import org.apache.ibatis.type.JdbcType;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.MappedTypes;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeHandler;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;

import java.sql.*;

@MappedTypes(DateTime.class)
public class DateTimeTypeHandler implements TypeHandler {

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeHandler#setParameter(java.sql.PreparedStatement, int, java.lang.Object, org.apache.ibatis.type.JdbcType)
     */
    public void setParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, Object parameter, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException {
        if (parameter != null) {
            ps.setTimestamp(i, new Timestamp(((DateTime) parameter).getMillis()));
        } else {
            ps.setTimestamp(i, null);
        }
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeHandler#getResult(java.sql.ResultSet, java.lang.String)
     */
    public Object getResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName) throws SQLException {
        Timestamp ts = rs.getTimestamp(columnName);
        if (ts != null) {
            return new DateTime(ts.getTime(), DateTimeZone.UTC);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeHandler#getResult(java.sql.CallableStatement, int)
     */
    public Object getResult(CallableStatement cs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
        Timestamp ts = cs.getTimestamp(columnIndex);
        if (ts != null) {
            return new DateTime(ts.getTime(), DateTimeZone.UTC);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeHandler#getResult(java.sql.ResultSet, int)
     */
    public Object getResult(ResultSet rs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
        Timestamp ts = rs.getTimestamp(columnIndex);
        if (ts != null) {
            return new DateTime(ts.getTime(), DateTimeZone.UTC);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to serialiaze some Java to Json, Json to java using the following beans :

**DataBean**

```
package com.common.config;

import com.common.business.user.Employee;
import com.common.config.yaml.DatabaseConfig;
import com.common.mybatis.typehandler.DateTimeTypeHandler;
import com.commonTools.model.DBObject;
import com.commonTools.model.Snoop;
import com.commonTools.model.SnoopDBObject;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeHandler;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean;
import org.mybatis.spring.annotation.MapperScan;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource;

@Configuration
@Import(DatabaseConfig.class)
@MapperScan("com.persistence")
public class DataBean {

    @Autowired DatabaseConfig _databaseConfig;

    @Bean
    public DateTimeTypeHandler dateTimeTypeHandler(){
        return new DateTimeTypeHandler();
    }
    @Bean
    public SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource() {
        SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClass(org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.class);
        dataSource.setUsername(_databaseConfig.getUsername());
        dataSource.setPassword(_databaseConfig.getPassword());
        dataSource.setUrl(_databaseConfig.getUrl());
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    public SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactory() throws Exception {
        SqlSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setTypeHandlers(new TypeHandler[] {
            new DateTimeTypeHandler(),
        });
        sessionFactory.setTypeAliases(new Class[] {
            DateTime.class,
            Employee.class,
            DBObject.class,
            Snoop.class,
            SnoopDBObject.class
        });
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

and **JacksonBean**

```
package com.common.config;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.PropertyAccessor;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MapperFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.JodaModule;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class JacksonBean {

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();


        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        mapper.configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, true);

//      # TEST 0 (TODO: see result when activated using JodaTime)
        mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
        mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS );
//      mapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'ZZZ (z)"));

//      # TEST 1 (Res: fail sometimes when too much depth)
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false); // true default

//      # TEST 2 (Res: too much depth)
        mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
                .setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.CREATOR, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
                .setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.SETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
                .setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.GETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
                .setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.IS_GETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);

        return mapper;
    }

}
```

This work well, I am able to serialize the DateTime object but this does not work when I execute the following **EmployeeServiceTest** :

```
package com.common.service.user;


import com.common.business.user.Employee;
import com.common.config.DataBean;
import com.commonTools.SessionIdentifierGenerator;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class, classes = {DataBean.class, EmployeeService.class})
public class EmployeeServiceTest implements EmployeeServiceDAO {

    private static final String SAMPLE_NAME = "JUnitTestUser_";

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService _employeeService;


    private String getRandomName(){
        return SAMPLE_NAME + new SessionIdentifierGenerator().nextSessionId();
    }

    @Test
    public void test_getAll(){
        List<Employee> employeeList = this.getAll();
        Employee testEmployee = new Employee();
        testEmployee.setFirstName(getRandomName());
        testEmployee.setLastName(getRandomName());
        this.save(testEmployee);
        assertNotNull("should have an id", testEmployee.getId());
        List<Employee> employeeListIncremented = this.getAll();
        assertEquals("Should have +1 in list", employeeList.size() + 1 , employeeListIncremented.size());
        this.removeById(testEmployee.getId());
        assertTrue("should be deleted", this.getById(testEmployee.getId()) == null);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_getById(){
        Employee testEmployee = new Employee();
        testEmployee.setFirstName(getRandomName());
        testEmployee.setLastName(getRandomName());
        this.save(testEmployee);
        assertNotNull("should have an id", testEmployee.getId());
        Employee employeeById = this.getById(testEmployee.getId());
        assertEquals("should be equal id", employeeById.getId(), testEmployee.getId());
        this.removeById(testEmployee.getId());
        assertTrue("should be deleted", this.getById(testEmployee.getId()) == null);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_getFromFirstName(){
        Employee testEmployee = new Employee();
        testEmployee.setFirstName(getRandomName());
        testEmployee.setLastName(getRandomName());
        this.save(testEmployee);
        assertNotNull("should have an id", testEmployee.getId());
        Employee employeeFromFirstName = this.getFromFirstName(testEmployee.getFirstName());
        assertEquals("should be equal id", employeeFromFirstName.getId(), testEmployee.getId());
        this.removeById(testEmployee.getId());
        assertTrue("should be deleted", this.getById(testEmployee.getId()) == null);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_save() {
        Employee testEmployee = new Employee();
        testEmployee.setFirstName(getRandomName());
        testEmployee.setLastName(getRandomName());
        this.save(testEmployee);
        assertNotNull("should have an id", testEmployee.getId());
//      assertTrue("should have a creation datetime", null != testEmployee.getCreation().getDateTime() );
        String firstNameTmp = getRandomName();
        testEmployee.setFirstName(firstNameTmp);
        this.save(testEmployee);
        Employee editedEmployee = this.getById(testEmployee.getId());
        assertEquals("should have first name \""+firstNameTmp+"\"", firstNameTmp, editedEmployee.getFirstName());
        this.removeById(testEmployee.getId());
        assertTrue("should be deleted", this.getById(testEmployee.getId()) == null);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_removeById() {
        test_save();
    }

    public List<Employee> getAll() {
        return _employeeService.getAll();
    }

    public Employee getById(Integer id) {
        return _employeeService.getById(id);
    }

    public Employee getFromFirstName(String firstName) {
        return _employeeService.getFromFirstName(firstName);
    }

    public Employee save(Employee employee) {
        _employeeService.save(employee);
        return employee;
    }

    public void removeById(Integer id) {
        _employeeService.removeById(id);
    }
}
```

These questions comes in my mind :

1. It's not very handy to serialize `@Configuration` class like DatabaseConfig, this because Spring also include it's own properties in the serialization chain.
2. The UnitTest fail because of `// assertTrue("should have a creation datetime", null != testEmployee.getCreation().getDateTime() );`, in the test , getCreation is null while it shouldn't, how should I initialize the Jackson to DateTime Jodatime mapping during the test .
3. I also notice the test doesn't rollback the database when it fails. I used to do Unit Testing with javascript and I was used to the before(), after() method that do post install and pre install of the test, is there a conveniant way to achieve that.
4. Beside all I have done here, is this the most appropriate way to design a RESTful api ?